# Amazon S3: how to use/load an mp3 file simultaneously

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, soundmanager2, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using Amazon S3 to store some mp3 files. 
My web application, uses the Soundmanager2 javascript library to load the files from the Amazon bucket, and play them to users.

When the first user clicks on an mp3, soundmanager starts playing the file, and as intended, caches the rest of the song as it is being played.
Problem is, if a second user clicks on the same mp3, he must wait until the first user caches the whole song, which is unacceptable for my website.

I understand that Amazon S3 somehow 'streams' the file exclusively to the first request. Is there a way to be able to use that file **simultaneously**, i.e. users be able to play the same mp3's at the same time?

Also, would the CloudFront functionality solve this issue?

Thank you for your help!
Alex

(By the way, my application is built on Ruby on Rails 3, and hosted on Heroku)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limitation in S3 that restricts simultaneous downloads of a single object.

I would suggest that you use a tool, like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), to inspect the HTTP requests and see if another service is causing the second client's request to be delayed.

Comment: You are absolutely right! I was playing the mp3 file from two separate tabs of the same browser. I called a friend of mine, and asked him to test playing the file at the same time with me, and it worked! Guess Amazon only allows simultaneous connections from different locations. Anyway, many thanks for the help! Much appreciated!